# How to get ResultSetMetaData from Entity Manager?

Tags: java, jpa, resultset

Is there a way to get the `MetaData` of the result returned by executing a `nativeQuery` on an Entity Manager in JPA?

Answer (score 9):

AFAIK there is no way of getting the result set metadata since there is no way really, of getting the result set. But, turn it around: what do you want the meta data for? Most of the information from the result set metadata you already have to have to be able to annotate your entity classes.
The result set from conventional SQL/JDBC and the List you get from the EntityManager differs conceptually even if they can express the same semantics.

Comment: Thanks.. I've used regular JDBC scince metadata here is very important as I am doing some generic code that accept some generic sql.

Comment: Not to be grumpy and all but if the answer satisfies you, why not mark it as answered or mark up my answer?