# Can I retrieve column names in a JPA native sql query?

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get ResultSetMetaData from enity manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180339/how-to-get-resultsetmetadata-from-enity-manager)

Given a simple table (`example_table`) with the following columns: `id, first_name, last_name` is it possible, by executing a JPA native sql query `em.createNativeQuery("select * from example_table")` retrieve the column names as well as the data? Running the `getResultList()` on the query only returns the data. How else can I retrieve the column names?

Comment: This question is marked as a dupe of a question about how to get metadata for an entity. This is NOT a duplicate. In this question's case, there is no entity to query the entity manager for `ResultSetMetaData`.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52745827/5223047).

Comment: Possible Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44626609/getting-column-names-from-a-jpa-native-query

Answer (score -1):

try this

> em.unwrap(Session.class).getDescriptor(Currency.class).getFields()