# Spring Boot getColumns

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is there an interface in Spring that implements jdbc metadata getColumns method and can auto inject into a generic entity? I'm wanting to use Spring to condense my data retrieval code but my schema and table aren't known until run time so I dont see a way to use Repository/Entity.

Comment: This may be you are looking for - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44626609/getting-column-names-from-a-jpa-native-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`JdbcTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) or [`NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html).

For queries returning a single row, call [`queryForMap(String sql, Object... args)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForMap-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-), which returns a *generic entity*, also known as a `Map<String,Object>` object, keyed by column name.

For queries returning multiple rows, call [`queryForList(String sql, Object... args)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForList-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-), which returns a `List` of such `Map<String,Object>` objects *(generic entities)*.

Comment: Used JdbcTemplate execute with connection callback. Thanks for the input