# Good way for getting metadata from a Database?

Tags: java, swing, jpa, ejb, persistence

I have a swing application that creates a JTable mapped to a table in sqlserver database,
So far I've used JDBC to retreive the metadata for the table and then recreate it in my java application as a JTable. This is the code that retrieves the metadata

```
    public ResultSetMetaData getMetaData(String table) {

          // Load database driver if not already loaded
          try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

          // Establish network connection to database
          Connection con =
               DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=DBank;integratedSecurity=tr   ue");

          Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
          ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM " +table);


          return rs.getMetaData();

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          return null;


}
```

And it works fine, But now I want to transfer all of my connectivity to EJB JPA, So my question is, What would be a good way to retrieve metadata from the DBs' table using JPA if that's even possible?

Comment: Check these two, see if they are relevant to your case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599412/getting-a-tables-metadata-without-using-resultset-in-java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951053/obtaining-table-metadata-from-mysql-in-java?rq=1

Comment: hmm ... maybe the [MetaModel API](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/metamodel) as starting point?

Comment: [searching a bit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180339/how-to-get-resultsetmetadata-from-entity-manager) (hint, hint :-) it looks like there is no way to get the metadata (not those retrieved from a resultSet) from the EntityManager